# Getting ClassNotFoundException for class defined in external jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a spring boot application `app.jar` that uses Apache Camel for integrating hosts.
Currently, both XML routes and custom camel JAVA classes(processors) are packaged within the spring boot application.
My requirement is to move XML routes and custom camel processors outside the spring boot jar so that during deployment users can write their own custom XML routes and processors.
I was able to externalize XML routes using `camel.springboot.routes-include-pattern = file:${workdir.path}/camel/routes/*.xml`
And I created a jar inside `workdir/camel/libs/` (using gradle java-libray plugin) that includes all required custom camel JAVA classes. One such class is as shown below:

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.camel.AggregationStrategy;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.dependencies.from.other.springboot.application.XYZ;

@Component
public class GenericParallelApiAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        //Business logic here
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to run the spring boot project by adding the above jar in spring boot classpath as shown below:

```
java -Dworkdir.path=D:/sample/workdir -cp "D:/sample/app.jar;D:/sample/workdir/camel/libs/*" org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.example.GenericParallelApiAggregationStrategy] for bean with name 'genericParallelApiAggregationStrategy' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/sample/workdir/libs/camel-sample.jar!/com/example/GenericParallelApiAggregationStrategy.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/AggregationStrategy
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:686)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/AggregationStrategy
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.AggregationStrategy
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 58 more
```

And this is the `build.gradle` file of sample-camel project:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.5.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-starter:3.11.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.4'

    implementation files('D:\\sample\\app.jar')
}
```

Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to add local jars try this:

Add local jar to your module gradle (Not to the app gradle file):

```
    repositories {
         flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
         }
    }

    dependencies {
       implementation name: 'app'
    }
```

Comment: No, adding local dependency to jar is not an issue. The library project is getting compiled. Only when we when we are trying to run the Springboot app with the library jar in classpath, i am getting the error.